# Translating "We see great fortune in your daughters' lives, my friend"

Tags: sentence-translation

So I'm just learning Latin, and I'm not sure if I got this translation right. Whenever you use 'in' in Latin, the predicate noun is refers to and the noun the follows it has to have the same form right?

Let me know if I made a mistake:
*Fōturnam multam in tuam vītam fīllarum vidēmus, meus amīcus.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation is certainly in the right direction, but it needs some polishing:

1. I'm not sure whether *multam* is a good way to say "great" here. You could also consider *magnam*, *grandem*, *tantam*.
   You can compare these words in [any online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).
   I wouldn't say *multam* is wrong; it's just that there may be better options.
2. If you want to say "in X" (location) rather than "into X" (movement), the word following *in* should be in ablative rather than accusative.
   As an anonymous suggested edit mentions, you might want to change *vita* ("life") to plural as in English.
   You currently have singular accusative.
   The singular ablative would give you *in vita* ("in the life"), whereas in plural you'd have *in vitis* ("in the lives").
3. There are typos: "daughter" is *filia*, not *filla*, and "fortune" is *fortuna*, not *foturna*. (Some words do have legitimate spelling variants, but I haven't seen these before.)
4. The word *tua* modifies the daughters.
   After all, it is the *filiae* that are yours, not the *vita*.
   Therefore *tua* should have the form of the noun it modifies: *tuarum*.
   Because these two words go together, it is natural to place them next to each other, although it is not necessary.
5. When you address someone, the addressee is not in nominative but in vocative.
   Therefore *meus amicus* should be *mi amice*.
6. If you want to keep track of vowel quantity (which is a good practice!), the *a* in the plural genitive ending *-arum* is long.

With these corrections, your sentence becomes:

> Fortūnam multam in vītīs fīliārum tuārum vidēmus, mī amīce.